# Spring Boot any way to define a JTA resource?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, spring-boot

Is there a simple way to expose a resource as JNDI resource so that it satisfies the JTA data source reference in `persistence.xml` (*already there, have to reuse it for some reasons)*?

If not in Spring Boot, can we do it using Java EE, like using an `@Resource` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your own JNDI context using the Apache classes used by Tomcat to create an *InitialContext*, something like this: https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit

You could set that up in a *@Configuration* class where you create your DataSource.